# cant ssh to aws server

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, traceroute

Below is my traceroute output:

```
[root@localhost .ssh]# traceroute -p 22 ec2-54-206-114-41.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
traceroute to ec2-54-206-114-41.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com (41.114.206.54), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.2.1)  1.319 ms  1.775 ms  1.770 ms
 2  lo0.bras2.bne3.on.ii.net (150.101.32.110)  9.431 ms  9.678 ms  9.990 ms
 3  po10.bras2.bne3.on.ii.net (150.101.35.84)  10.744 ms  11.524 ms  12.398 ms
 4  ae19.cr1.bne4.on.ii.net (150.101.40.132)  30.149 ms  31.162 ms  32.559 ms
 5  ae6.br1.syd7.on.ii.net (150.101.33.76)  43.314 ms  43.636 ms  43.882 ms
 6  be14.cr2.syd7.on.ii.net (150.101.40.129)  37.240 ms  24.351 ms  25.093 ms
 7  syd-gls-har-wgw1-be-40.tpgi.com.au (203.219.107.253)  25.274 ms  25.697 ms  26.548 ms
 8  203-221-3-4.tpgi.com.au (203.221.3.4)  30.616 ms 203-221-3-68.tpgi.com.au (203.221.3.68)  34.130 ms  30.571 ms
 9  10ge3-4.core1.sjc1.he.net (72.52.93.37)  181.601 ms  181.215 ms  181.468 ms
10  10ge7-2.core1.sjc2.he.net (72.52.92.118)  199.515 ms 100ge1-1.core1.sjc2.he.net (184.105.213.94)  211.927 ms 10ge7-2.core1.sjc2.he.net (72.52.92.118)  204.223 ms
11  100ge1-2.core1.nyc4.he.net (184.105.81.214)  243.232 ms  254.728 ms  255.018 ms
12  100ge7-2.core1.lon2.he.net (72.52.92.165)  374.880 ms * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

My network skills are a bit shabby, I'm guessing the problem is my isp is blocking me from connecting to my aws ec2 instance? I have a default aws account with a centos image im trying to connect to. It has port 22 open in its default security group apart from that I haven't change any of the default aws config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you assign ElasticIP, the public ip of the instance will be changed after stop/start (but not after reboot).